# Does running ifop on a system impact its bandwidth?

Tags: pcap, bandwidth, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I want to know if I continuously run iftop as a daemon on a linux machine would it impact the bandwidth of the system it's running on?

Answer (score 0):

It will largely depend on your system load. If your current bandwidth is limited by the CPU, iftop will most likely negatively impact the bandwidth (as it will consume additional CPU time). **You should measure this on your own system.**

---

As an example, I've configured 1) iptables to drop all packets from my second network interface and 2) [MoonGen](https://github.com/emmericp/MoonGen), on a second computer, to inject a continuous load of ~6.9 Mpps on that interface.

- Without iftop running, iptables received and dropped ~5 Mpps.
- With iftop running, iptables received and dropped ~2.5 Mpps. Other packets were dropped at the network card, because the CPU didn't have enough time to retrieve them.

On my system, with this configured bandwidth, iftop adds an overhead of about 50%. This has to do with how iftop operates (sniff packets on interfaces) and could probably be improved in newer Linux versions that have ways to count packets directly in the kernel (using eBPF). In particular, you might want to check the [bcc-tools](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc).